# Angular 5: Get checkbox values in a JSON object with the check box name as key and true/false as value?

Tags: json, angular5

I have a form with checkbox names say Apple and Mango. 
When I check one/both/none I would like the value to store in a JSON on submitting the form.

How to do the same in Angular 5?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can achieve it by Reactive Form:

xxx.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
     <div>
         <input type="checkbox" formControlName="apple">
         <input type="checkbox" formControlName="mango">
     </div>
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

xxx.component.ts

```
form = this.fb.group({
    apple: true,  // initial value
    mango: false
  }
);

onSubmit() {
  console.log(this.form.value); // this is JSON
}
```

If you want to store string `Apple` or `Mango` you can validate the boolean results returned from `this.form.value`